# How to get inner content as a variable without rendering in LitElements

Tags: html, typescript, web-component, lit-element, lit

I am using my lit element like this

```
<my-header>MyHeading</my-header>
```

And I have my lit element's render method:

```
render() {
  return html`
    <h3><slot></slot></h3>
  `;
}
```

which is working perfectly. Now I want the inner content i.e. "MyHeading" in my lit element's class as a value(not to render). Is there any way to get that innerHTML or as a text?

Note: my use case can be to set another property of rendered content like

```
render() {
  return html`
    <h3 id="${//How to get that 'MyHeading' here??}"><slot></slot></h3>
  `;
}
```

Is it possible to get inner content as a value?

Comment: only with a ``setTimeout`` in the ``connectedCallback`` so all DOM is parsed, can be queried and updated

Comment: Why not use updateComplete rather than settimeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you get when you learn new stuff **starting** with a Library or Framework;
You learn the Tool, not the Technology.

The child-elements of your customElement are **not available** yet
when the `connectedCallback` fires

- so you wait till the EventLoop is empty (and thus know all children are parsed)
- Or use any of the Library methods that (usually) fire even later than a `setTimeout`
- Or, even more blunty, like many blogs show, execute the script that creates your Element
  **after the whole DOM is parsed** by marking it a `type="module"` or `async` or `defer`

```html
<script>
  customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super().attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML = `<h3><slot></slot></h3>`
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // wait till innerHTML is parsed
        let title = this.innerText;
        console.log("Reflected from lightDOM:" , title);
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector("h3").id = title;
      })
    }
  })
</script>

<my-element>
  Hello Web Components!
</my-element>
```

Comment: I got the answer but did not  understand what you mentioned about 'learning new stuff'. Anyways thanks.

Comment: Learn Web Components by learning the core technology. If you learn Web Components by starting with Lit you learn a Tool, not the Technology. It is like cooking, you can buy a can of chicken broth in de supermarket (Lit) or make your own broth.